# Shiny selectInput in DT datatable - keep selectized when data updated

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

In my Shiny app I have a DT datatable with selectInputs which are updated in response to user input. I am using JavaScript to bind/unbind the selectInputs and to selectize them for styling and search capability. I am using DT::datatableProxy() and DT::replaceData() to update the selectInputs in the datatable, rather than shiny::updateSelectInput(). This is because in my real app, selectInputs may be removed or added from the table in response to user input.
I have a minor issue. When the selectInputs are first rendered, they are selectized (styling and search ability). However, once the user clicks a button and the selectInputs and table are updated, the selectInputs lose their selectized style.

How can I keep the selectized style when the table and selectInputs get updated?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Selectize input ids
selectize_ids <- function(ids) {
  tmp <- paste0("  $('#", ids, "')")
  tmp <- paste0(tmp, ".selectize();")
  c(
    "function(settings){",
      tmp,
    "}"
  )
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(style = "display: none;", selectInput(inputId = "dummy", label = NULL, choices = 1:2)),
    actionButton(inputId = "my_button", label = "Click Me"),
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    input_ids <- c("A_1", "A_2")
    df_reactive <- reactive({
      data.frame(
        A = sapply(input_ids, function(id) as.character(selectInput(
          inputId = id, 
          label = NULL, 
          choices = paste0(c("a", "b", "c"), input$my_button)
        )))
      )
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        data = isolate(df_reactive()),
        selection = "none",
        rownames = F,
        escape = F,
        options = list(
          initComplete = JS(selectize_ids(input_ids)),
          preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
          drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
        )
      )
    })
    
    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy(outputId = "table")
    observe({
      DT::replaceData(proxy = proxy, data = df_reactive(), rownames = F)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a call to `selectize` in the `drawCallback`:

```r
          drawCallback = 
            JS('function() {
                 Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());
                 $("#A_1").selectize();
                 $("#A_2").selectize();
               }')
```

[image]